# Laravel - Route pattern cannot reference variable name more than once

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am working on a legacy code, a project built with Laravel 5.2, and I am getting an error:

```
Route pattern "/api/v0/taxonomy/{term}/{{term}}" cannot reference variable name "term" more than once.
```

For this route:

```
/post/106
```

This is are my routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'v0'], function () {
        Route::get('route/{a?}/{b?}/{c?}/{d?}', 'DynamicRouteController@resolve');
        Route::get('id/{id}', 'DynamicRouteController@resolveId');
        Route::get('search', 'SearchController@search');
        Route::resource('taxonomy/{term}','TaxonomyController');
    });
});
```

Not sure, why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you define a route as a resource then Laravel seems to create all the routes necessary for your resource: GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE.

So you would just need to define `Route::resource('taxonomy','TaxonomyController');` or `Route::resource('taxonomy.post','TaxonomyPostController');`

Check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: Yes, every night before going to bed.

Comment: When Laravel is more than a framework and more of a religion :))

Comment: you are right, but you should explain that kind of things in the answer rather than in the answer of a comment... I mean, if it's worth extract the info from the link to answer a cheeky comment, it is double worth to extract it to answer the legit answer. And yes, Laravel is a religion and Taylor Otwell is its prophet :)

Answer (score 4):

You just need rename your route parameter like this:

```
Route::resource('taxonomy/{term}','TaxonomyController', ['parameters'
=> ['{term}' => 'your_name']]);
```

be careful!!!!. you need insert bracket. this will cause wrong result:

```
Route::resource('taxonomy/{term}','TaxonomyController', ['parameters'
=> ['term' => 'your_name']] );
```

> attention:
> 'your_name' should not be same as your parameter so this method make wrong
> result.

```
Route::resource('taxonomy/{term}','TaxonomyController', ['parameters'
    => ['{term}' => 'term']});
```

Comment: I am getting `Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $id ]] in class App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController` for similar case : web.php (https://pastebin.com/Y7P1jqZ1) with ProjectsController (https://pastebin.com/A8ULNRd8). Could please let me know ?

Comment: in your controller __construct method you cant use $id. test this: 
`Route::resource(
     'projects/{project}',
     'ProjectsController',
     [
      'parameters' => [
       '{project}'=>'id',
      ],
     ]
    );`  @maan81